# Mongodb: Client side Field Level encryption - integration with Hashicorp vault

Tags: mongodb, hashicorp-vault

We plan to use client-side field-level encryption for some confidential fields in our product. To generate and manage the Customer Master key, we want to use Hashicorp Vault. KMS providers currently supported are only: Amazon Web Services KMS and Locally Managed Keyfile.

To work with Hashicorp Vault, it seems, we need to choose Locally Managed Keyfile as the KMS provider. This means that the Master key will be fetched from Vault in memory and then used in the code to encrypt/decrypt the DEK (Data Encryption Key). Ideally, the decryption of DEK should happen in the vault itself as a best practice, and master key should not be brought out of Vault.

Is there a way to achieve this? There are numerous articles around encryption at rest and integration with Hashicorp vault, but none of them is for CSFLE. Need help if anyone is using CSFLE.

Thanks

Comment: You can request the functionality via https://feedback.mongodb.com/.

Comment: @D.SM  Thanks for the suggestion. Just requested the functionality: https://feedback.mongodb.com/forums/924286-drivers/suggestions/41197198-csfle-integration-with-more-kms-providers-like-h